# Compactness of subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: compactness

The following is a problem from my analysis homework:

Let $A$ be an infinite set in $\mathbb{R}$ with a single accumulation point in $A$. Must $A$ be compact?

What I'm having trouble understanding is the hypothesis. How can an infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ contain only $1$ of its accumulation points? Take $[0,1)$ for example, its accumulation points are $\{x ~| ~x \in [0,1]\}$ correct? That means it contains an infinite number of its accumulation points (all but $1$ in fact).

Comment: Consider $\{0\}\cup\{1/n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Is $1$ not also an accumulation point? For any $\epsilon > 0$, isn't there always a $y \ne 1 \in \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ such that $y \in \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cap D(1,\epsilon) $?

Comment: No, not if $\epsilon<\frac12$.

Comment: Ah. Yes, I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an example of such an $A$ that is compact, consider $A = \{0\}\cup\{1/n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

For an example of such an $A$ that isn't compact, consider $A = \Bbb Z \cup\{1/n\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** can you find such a non bounded set?